# Can command line flags in Go be set to mandatory?

Tags: go, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Is there a way how to set that certain flags are mandatory, or do I have to check for their presence on my own?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package does not support mandatory or required flags (meaning the flag must be specified explicitly).

What you can do is use sensible default values for (all) flags. And if a flag is something like there is no sensible default, check the value at the start of your application and halt with an error message. You should do flag value validation anyway (not just for required flags), so this shouldn't mean any (big) overhead, and this is a good practice in general.

Answer (score 22):

As [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31786364/55504), the `flag` package does not provide this feature directly and usually you can (and should) be able to provide a sensible default. For cases where you only need a small number of explicit arguments (e.g. an input and output filename) you could use positional arguments (e.g. after `flag.Parse()` check that `flag.NArg()==2` and then `input, output := flag.Arg(0), flag.Arg(1)`).

If however, you have a case where this isn't sensible; say a few integer flags you want to accept in any order, where any integer value is reasonable, but no default is. Then you can use the [`flag.Visit`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Visit) function to check if the flags you care about were explicitly set or not. I think this is the only way to tell if a flag was explicitly set to it's default value (not counting a custom `flag.Value` type with a `Set` implementation that kept state).

For example, perhaps something like:

```
    required := []string{"b", "s"}
    flag.Parse()

    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    flag.Visit(func(f *flag.Flag) { seen[f.Name] = true })
    for _, req := range required {
        if !seen[req] {
            // or possibly use `log.Fatalf` instead of:
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "missing required -%s argument/flag\n", req)
            os.Exit(2) // the same exit code flag.Parse uses
        }
    }
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/FqKzq_1ICs)

This would produce an error if either the "-b" or "-s" flag was not explicitly set.

Answer (score 12):

I like [`github.com/jessevdk/go-flags`](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags) package to use in CLI. It provides a `required` attribute, to set a mandatory flag:

```
var opts struct {
...
    // Example of a required flag
    Name string `short:"n" long:"name" description:"A name" required:"true"`
...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

[`go-flags`](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags) lets you declare both required flags and required positional arguments:

```
var opts struct {
    Flag string `short:"f" required:"true" name:"a flag"`
    Args struct {
        First   string `positional-arg-name:"first arg"`
        Sencond string `positional-arg-name:"second arg"`
    } `positional-args:"true" required:"2"`
}
args, err := flags.Parse(&opts)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have flag path, simply check if *path contains some value

```
var path = flag.String("f", "", "/path/to/access.log")
flag.Parse()
if *path == "" {
    usage()
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Instead of `usage()`, `flag.Usage()` could be used.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31795922/11075587) but, in my case default values are usually environment values. For example,

```
dsn := flag.String("dsn", os.Getenv("MYSQL_DSN"), "data source name")
```

And in this case, I want to check if the values are set from invocation (usually local development) or environment var (prod environment).

So with some minor modifications, it worked for my case.

Using [flag.VisitAll](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#VisitAll) to check the value of all flags.

```
required := []string{"b", "s"}
flag.Parse()

seen := make(map[string]bool)
flag.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
    if f.Value.String() != "" {
        seen[f.Name] = true
    }
})
for _, req := range required {
    if !seen[req] {
        // or possibly use `log.Fatalf` instead of:
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "missing required -%s argument/flag\n", req)
        os.Exit(2) // the same exit code flag.Parse uses
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Test example in plauground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/0ybaFl_b9OX)

Comment: `seen` no longer means "seen" in your code but instead "empty string", at which point you'd be much better off just checking that `flag.Lookup(req).Value.String() != ""` and ditching the map entirely. You also may be better off by getting values from the environment in a different way rather than changing flag defaults (e.g. perhaps something like [`envflag`](https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/dchapes/envflag)).

Comment: I agree with the name but I wanted to keep the same as the previous solution because it was just an example of an adaptation to a solution that is not mine. On using another way, I still prefer to use [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) because it allows me to pass parameters by command line in a development environment and leave the environment variables for production.

Comment: Just for completeness (I don't expect anyone uses it), the above linked `envflag` package moved to [`envflag`](https://pkg.go.dev/hg.sr.ht/~dchapes/envflag.hg) since bitbucket deleted all non-git repositories :(.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full working example.

Work around the `Usage` and `DefValue` attributes, and wrap your flags into a struct.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type CliFlag struct {
    Required bool
    Usage    string
    Name     string
    Address  *string
}

func init() {
    flags := [...]CliFlag{
        {
            Required: true,
            Usage:    "(github.com) repository URI",
            Name:     "repo-uri",
            Address:  nil,
        },
        {
            Required: true,
            Usage:    "(Zombro) repository workspace",
            Name:     "repo-workspace",
            Address:  nil,
        },
        {
            Required: true,
            Usage:    "(zzio) repository slug",
            Name:     "repo-slug",
            Address:  nil,
        },
    }
    for i, f := range flags {
        f.Address = flag.String(f.Name, "", f.Usage)
        flags[i] = f
    }
    flag.Parse()
    missing := make([]string, 0)
    for _, f := range flags {
        if *f.Address == "" && f.Required {
            missing = append(missing, f.Name)
        }
    }
    if len(missing) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("missing required flags: %v \n", missing)
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main")
}
```

missing

```
$ go run . -repo-slug test                  
missing required flags: [repo-uri repo-workspace] 
Usage of /var/folders/mg/86n5kszs27bdqj0fpswvr0m00000gn/T/go-build2061541798/b001/exe/zzio:
  -repo-slug string
        (zzio) repository slug
  -repo-uri string
        (github.com) repository URI
  -repo-workspace string
        (Zombro) repository workspace
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A thing to note is that when you do:

```golang
password := flag.String("password", "", "the password")
flag.Parse()
```

The default is set by `flag.String`, not `flag.Parse`.

So if you instead do:

```golang
const unspecified = "\x00"
password := flag.String("password", "", "the password")
*password = unspecified
flag.Parse()
```

Then `*password == unspecified` if you don't specify it explicitly in the command line. This is my go to for strings when I want to distinguish "empty" from "unspecified".

Answer (score -1):

Or you could docopt, where you only have to write the "usage" text. Docopt interprets the usage text and creates an argument map. This opens up a whole lot of possibilities, all following the POSIX usage text standard. This library is available for about 20 languages already.

https://github.com/docopt/docopt.go

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/docopt/docopt-go"
)

const (
        Usage = `Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate ship new <name>...
  naval_fate ship <name> move <x> <y> [--speed=<kn>]
  naval_fate ship shoot <x> <y>
  naval_fate mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored|--drifting]
  naval_fate -h | --help
  naval_fate --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  --speed=<kn>  Speed in knots [default: 10].
  --moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
  --drifting    Drifting mine.`
)

func main() {
        args, _ := docopt.ParseDoc(Usage)
        fmt.Println(args)
}
```