# How to limit the range of values acceptable in string flag?

Tags: go, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I declare a string flag with a default value like this:

```
animalFlag := flag.String("typeOfAnimal", "Cat", "Type of animal")
```

I want to force that user could only give a specific string (like `"Dog"`, `"Lion"`) and not some random string like `"Rose"`.
How do I enforce this in Go?

Answer (score 1):

The [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package does not support limiting the valid / accepted set of values for flags.

What you can do is perform flag value validation, and this is a good practice in general: check the value at the start of your application and halt with an error message if the provided value is invalid (according to your arbitrary rules).

See related question: [Can command line flags in Go be set to mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786215/can-command-line-flags-in-go-be-set-to-mandatory/31786364#31786364)

Comment: "The flag package does not support limiting the valid / accepted set of values for flags." One can stick the validation logic into an implementation of the [flag.Value interface](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Value), though, producing good error messages: https://play.golang.org/p/eXhFj1DYCzC